# Satzstellung und Bedeutung von "auch"

Tags: semantics

Leider konnte ich zur Bedeutung und Verwendung von *auch* keine Einschrärkungen für den Gebrauch in folgendem Kontext finden:

- Ich habe auch keinen Hunger.
- Auch ich habe keinen Hunger.

Sind die beiden Möglichkeiten der Verwendung von "auch" grammatikalisch korrekt und, falls ja, welchen Sinn tragen sie?

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 1):

Das Adverb *auch* folgt denselben Regeln wie das Adverb *nicht*:

> Ich habe nicht Hunger, sondern Durst.
>
> Ich habe auch Hunger, nicht nur Durst.
>
> Nicht ich habe Hunger, sondern er.
>
> Auch ich habe Hunger, nicht nur er.
>
> Ich habe Hunger, er nicht.
>
> Ich habe Hunger, er auch.

Es wird also der Satzteil bestätigt, der dem *auch* folgt. Soll das Verb in Position 2 bestätigt werden, muss *auch* allerdings an das Ende des Satzes wandern:

> Sie riecht das Essen nicht.
>
> Sie riecht das Essen auch.

---

Kombinationen aus Adverben wie *nicht*, *auch*, *nur*, *immer*, *nie* etc. treten sehr häufig auf und haben je nach Reihenfolge der Wörter abweichende Bedeutungen.

> Ich rieche das Essen nicht. Er riecht es auch nicht.
>
> Er sieht das Essen nur. Er riecht es nicht auch.

Auch hier gilt zum Verständnis wieder, dass das Adverb den nachfolgenden Satzteil – hier das folgende Adverb – modifiziert.

Answer (score 0):

> - Ich habe auch keinen Hunger.
> - Auch ich habe keinen Hunger.
>
> Sind die beiden Möglichkeiten der Verwendung von "auch" grammatikalisch korrekt und,

Ja, beide Verwendungen sind grammatikalisch korrekt

> falls ja, welchen Sinnn tragen sie?

In beiden Fällen bezieht sich *auch* auf eine oder mehrere Personen, die gleichwohl *keinen Hunger haben*.

Eine weitere denkbare Verwendung wäre:

- Auch habe ich keinen Hunger

in Addition zu

- Ich habe keinen Durst, auch habe ich keinen Hunger

Answer (score 0):

Korrekt sind beide. Aber was die Bedeutung angeht muss ich meinen Vorrednern widersprechen. Im Ersten Beispielsatz kommt es auf die Betonung an:

> Ich habe auch keinen *Hunger*.
>   Auch habe ich keinen Hunger.

Ich habe nicht nur {keinen Durst; Bauchschmerzen; schlechte Laune} sondern auch keinen Hunger.

---

> Ich habe *auch* keinen Hunger.
>   *Ich* habe auch keinen Hunger.
>   Auch ich habe keinen Hunger.

Nicht nur {du hast; er/sie hat} keinen Hunger sondern auch ich.

---

> Ich *habe* auch keinen Hunger.

Es scheint nicht nur so, dass ich keinen Hunger habe, sondern es ist wirklich so.

---

Die Varianten mit `Auch` am Anfang kommen in gesprochener Alltagssprache (jedenfalls in meinem sozialen Umfeld, und in den von mir konsumierten deutschsprachigen Medien) nicht vor. Diese Satzstellung fühlt sich gekünstelt (oder meinetwegen literarisch, veraltet, ...) an.